# Create my own sink with SinkFunction in Scala

Tags: scala, apache-flink

I want to create my own Sink using scala for Flink and for that I need to extend the interface [SinkFunction](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-master/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/sink/SinkFunction.Context.html).

But I can't override the following invoke method.

```
default void invoke(IN value, Context context) throws Exception {
    invoke(value);
}
```

This is my code:

```
class MySinkFunction(schema: String) extends SinkFunction[List[GenericRecord]] {
    override def invoke(elements: List[GenericRecord], context: Context) { ... }
```

This gives the following error:

```
Type Context takes type parameters
```

If I change the code to add any type parameter:

```
class MySinkFunction(schema: String) extends SinkFunction[List[GenericRecord]] {
    override def invoke(elements: List[GenericRecord], context: Context[Xpto]) { ... }
```

The error messages is different:

```
Method `invoke` overrides nothing.
```

I'm new to Scala, is there something to fix this that I'm missing ?

All the [examples](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/testing.html#junit-rule-miniclusterwithclientresource) that I see in scala uses the following deprecated method:

```
/**
 * @deprecated Use {@link #invoke(Object, Context)}.
 */
@Deprecated
default void invoke(IN value) throws Exception {}
```

And [StreamingFileSink.java](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-streaming-java/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/api/functions/sink/filesystem/StreamingFileSink.java#L431) implements using this:

```
...

@Public // Interface might be extended in the future with additional methods.
interface Context<T> {

    /** Returns the current processing time. */
    long currentProcessingTime();

    /** Returns the current event-time watermark. */
    long currentWatermark();

    /**
     * Returns the timestamp of the current input record or {@code null} if the element does not
     * have an assigned timestamp.
     */
    Long timestamp();
}
```

Is this `<T>` wrong placed since it isn't used in anywhere in SinkFunction.Context ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case You can simply go with:

```
override def invoke(elements: List[GenericRecord], context: SinkFunction.Context[_]) { ... }
```

And it should work like a charm.

Comment: Thanks, that was it!